# Take the first N elements from an infinite iterator or generator in Swift

Tags: python, swift, iterator, generator

I use generators a lot in Python. Now I try to do something similar in Swift.

From an infinite factorial generator in Python.

```py
def gen_factorial():
  current = 1
  N = 1
  while True:
    yield current
    N += 1
    current *= N
```

A Swift version would be

```swift
struct gen_factorial: Sequence, IteratorProtocol 
{
  var current = 1
  var N = 1
  mutating func next()-> Int?{
    defer {
      N += 1
      current *= N
    }
    return current
  }
}
```

I test it by taking the first 4 elements with

```swift
zip(1...4, 
    gen_factorial()
   ).map{$1}
```

And get `1, 2, 6, 24` as expected.

But when I want to write a helper function `take(n, gen)` to simplify it, I can't.

```swift
func take(_ n: Int, _ it: AnyIterator<Int>) -> [Int]{
  return zip(1...n, it).map {$1}
}

take(4, gen_factorial())
```

The error message is

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'gen_factorial' to expected argument type 'AnyIterator<Int>'
```

What type should `it` be, if not AnyIterator?

I am still new to Swift. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnyIterator` is a *concrete* type conforming to the `Iterator` (and `Sequence`) protocol. In order to pass your iterator to that function you would have to wrap it into an `AnyIterator`:

```
print(take(4, AnyIterator(gen_factorial())))
// [1, 2, 6, 24]
```

The better solution would be to make the function *generic* so that it takes an arbitrary sequence type as argument:

```
func take<S: Sequence>(_ n: Int, _ it: S) -> [S.Element]{
    return zip(1...n, it).map {$1}
}

print(take(4, gen_factorial()))
// [1, 2, 6, 24]
```

*Remarks:*

- Instead of your helper function you can use the existing [`prefix(_ maxLength:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3128808-prefix) method of `Sequence`:

  ```
  print(Array(gen_factorial().prefix(4)))
  // [1, 2, 6, 24]
  ```
- The Swift naming conventions for types a upper camel-case.

Comment: Sequence.prefix(n) is exactly what I want. Thanks!